# Not being redirected to Keycloak when enabling it on my Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I am following this guide to try and get my Spring application (made with JHipster) to use Keycloak for authentication. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak. I put the keycloak code into the `dependencies` and `dependencyManagement`, and I edit `src/main/resources/config/application.yml` with the following:

`keycloak:
    auth-server-url: https://my-keycloak-server.com/auth
    realm: my-realm
    resource: login-app
    public-client: true
    security-constraints:
        - securityCollections:
            - patterns: /api/*`

But when I load the site up, it does not redirect me to my keycloak server, and I get the below in the logs. The site was using username / passwords earlier, with those credentials being stored in my H2 database. But I'm now trying to change this over to a keycloak I have running.

That page does talk about getting the `access_token` and `refresh_token` from Keycloak, but I'm not sure if the keycloak code I have is supposed to do that automatically, or if I have too code in additional things for it.

```
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/application-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth, tokenUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth, tokenUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/account
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth, tokenUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/application-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth, tokenUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth, tokenUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth, tokenUrl: https://my-keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.undertow.ServletSessionTokenStore  : session was null, returning null
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.undertow.ServletSessionTokenStore  : session was null, returning null
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.undertow.ServletSessionTokenStore  : session was null, returning null
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://localhost:9061/api/application-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://localhost:9061/api/account
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/account
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/application-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/account
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/application-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z  INFO 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.undertow.ServletSessionTokenStore  : session was null, returning null
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/api/profile-info
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:9061/error
2020-04-14T18:41:14Z DEBUG 29291 - [  XNIO-2 task-4] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
```

Also in SecurityConfiguration.java, I still have things such as 
`http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
...
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()`. Do I have to change much of this code that once looked at the username/password for authentication?

Here is my complete SecurityConfiguration.java - WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
    private final SSOUserService ssoUserService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                 TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport,
                                 ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, SSOUserService ssoUserService) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
        this.ssoUserService = ssoUserService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()

            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

        if(applicationProperties.getSso().isEnabled()) {
            http.apply(ssoConfigurerAdapter());
        }
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }

    private IdAMSSOConfigurer ssoConfigurerAdapter() {
        /*
         * Set password encoder from this bean in this class.
         * We can't use dependency injection because it
         * creates a dependency cycle.
         */
        ssoUserService.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new IdAMSSOConfigurer(tokenProvider, ssoUserService);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
```

Comment: you'll have to post your _complete_ websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: @MarcoBehler I edited it

Comment: If you're using JHipster, just choose OAuth 2.0 / OIDC as your authentication type and it'll use Keycloak by default. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/04/java-11-java-12-jhipster-oidc